# Add a '+' to query for each <space> php

Tags: php, google-api

**Html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>What do you want?</h1>
    <form action="googleApi.php" method="post" />
    <input type="text" name="itemWanted" /> <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
//Escape the input
$itemQueried = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['itemWanted']);
```

How do I get this code to switch a `+` sign in for any space for the value `$_POST['itemWanted']` so right now, if i enter in 'bag', it works fine. But if I enter in 'Gucci Bag', it doesnt populate the array, because the query (to the script) looks like 'Gucci Bag', when the queries should really be '`Gucci+Bag`' if you use a space. How do I switch a `+` for a `<space>`?

Comment: Hang on, you want to have the client serve `gucci+bag` to the server, on form-submit? Or the server to serve `gucci+bag` to the *client*?

Comment: When the client types in gucci bag, the server should interpret that as gucci+bag

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), this will convert any spaces to `+`.

e.g.

```
urlencode("Gucci Bag"); // Will give "Gucci+Bag"
```

So just use `urlencode($_POST['itemWanted'])` instead of `$_POST['itemWanted']` and any spaces the user entered will be converted to `+` for when you create `$url`.

Comment: That's what I wrote, too. But re-reading, I think this is a client-side question...(though I could very well be wrong).

Comment: This works perfectly. Wow! Php has such amazing functionality built-in!

Comment: @David Any manipulation can still be done on the server before the input is used. It could be dangerous to just rely on client-side manipulation for something like this, since people could then break it by directly querying the server with data that hasn't been manipulated properly. That's not to say it couldn't be done client-side, just that the server should be able to cope with invalid data if it is :)

Comment: Absolutely, I just read the question and then re-read it, and every time I came up with a different interpretation of the meaning of the question. Sigh. I should learn to trust my instincts..! =)